# Python: Return string using while loop (no methods or for loops)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

So I have this function below where I want to return a new string where every ch is replaced with ch2:

```
def replace(s, ch, ch2):
'''(str, str, str) - > str
Return a new string where every instance of ch in s is replaced with ch2
Precondition: len(ch) == 1 and len(ch2) == 1
'''

i = 0
m = s[i]
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == ch:
        return ch2
    m = m + s[i]
    i += 1
return m
```

When I type this:

```
replace('razzmatazz', 'z', 'r')
```

I want the output to be this:

```
'rarrmatarr'
```

I tried several ways, but I'm only getting `'r' or 'rr'`.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: str has a method called `replace` which does what you want. Any particular reason you need to implement that by yourself?

Comment: They're practice questions given to me, and my instructor specifically told us not to use methods or for loops. Also, I want to learn how to do this using a while loop only as I'm still not comfortable using them.

Comment: Actually, you are using methods : `len(string) => string.__len__()`, `string[i] => string.__getitem__(i)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your're returning `ch2` from the function as soon as you find `ch` in your original string, so that can't work in the way you expect it to do. You have to add the correct character to a new string, and then return that string after you iterate over every character in the original string.

```
i = 0
m = ''
while i < len(s):
    m += ch2 if s[i] == ch else s[i]
    i += 1

return m
```

Also, as pointed in the other answers, there are better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I didn't know if and else could be on the same line!
And I thought all if-statements are always followed by a colon. Learned something new, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be.,

```
i = 0
m = s[i]
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == ch:
        m = m + ch2 // Here you are lagging.
     else   
        m = m + s[i]
    i += 1
return m
```

Because , In your code, when in the string `razzmatazz` if first `z` is matched then instead of replacing.,
it returns the `ch2` i.e  `r`. Hence you are getting `r`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, after running this code I'm now getting 'rrarzrzmatarzrz' instead of 'rarrmatarr'. 
Might you know how to fix this?

Comment: @user2489861 I have changed the code. Moreover you must try something rather than simply asking. :) No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use str.replace(), available in Python?

```
>>> s = 'razzmatazz'
>>> s.replace('z', 'r')
'rarrmatarr'
```

No need to create a custom function to get done what you want

Comment: Reason why is because we were specifically told not to use methods. Also, I want to learn how to do use the while loop better. I'm still having some trouble implementing it to get the desired results.

Comment: Understood. As most point out, you need to move the return statement out of the loop, as it will return whatever value it has at that point and cancel the loop execution with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is built in to the language

```
'razzmatazz'.replace('z', 'r')

'rarrmatarr'
```

If I would use your style I would write something more along the lines of:

```
def replace(s, ch, ch2):
    s2 = list(s)
    i=0
    while i < len(s):
        if s2[i] == ch:
            s2[i]=ch2
        i=i+1
    return "".join(s2)
```

Comment: I want to learn how to do use the while loop better. I'm still having trouble implementing it in some cases. Also, I was told I'm not supposed to use methods for my practice questions.

Comment: @user2489861. All right. Have a look at my update. The main issue is that you return after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

`return` immediately returns a value and exits the function, even if it's in a loop. You probably want to get rid of that `while` loop and use a nice `for` loop instead:

```
def replace(s, ch, ch2):
    '''(str, str, str) - > str
    Return a new string where every instance of ch in s is replaced with ch2
    Precondition: len(ch) == 1 and len(ch2) == 1
    '''

    result = ''

    for char in s:
        if char == ch:
            result += ch2
        else:
            result += char

    return result
```

Although it'd be better if you just used the built-in `str.replace` method:

```
def replace(s, ch, ch2):
    return s.replace(ch, ch2)
```

Or more concisely:

```
replace = str.replace
```